# How prevent to buy one item by two customers

Tags: php, paypal

I'm selling some stuff on my website using paypal IPN + PDT. I always check how many items are in the stock before payment. After customer makes his order, he is redirected into paypal for make payment. When payment is completed I'm updating database about selling stuff, until this moment I had no problem becouse I was selling unlimited items. I'm not sure what should I do in case where I have for example 10 items for sell, for example in this scenario:

There is last item for sell. Customer makes his order and he is going to pay on the paypal but he didn't payed yet (website  still showing that there is one item for sell ), meanwhile customer B see that there is one item left in stock so he is going to buy it too. in this scenario both customers will pay but only one (faster one) get his product.

What I must do to dont make this happen ?

Comment: Do you use shopping basket? If item is in a shopping basket it is not available to other customers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I can't give you a code answer without seeing yours first, but here's how it could be done on paper :

- When customer A clicks the  "Pay" button, the item quantity is updated in the database
- If the payment goes through, do nothing, if the payment doesn't go through (cancelled, incorrect payment informations, etc) then revert the quantity back to the original

This should work fine as long as you do a final "quantity check" when the user clicks the checkout button. Let's say that both customer A and customer B have an item X in the cart, and there's only one left. They can't both pay for the item, since your system would check the quantity before redirecting to Paypal, and as soon as one of the customers do click on the button, the quantity is updated to reflect the purchase.

Comment: That's right but if customer A clicks "Pay" button system will update it in the database then customer is leaving my page to make payment on paypal website but what if he changes his mind and he didn't pay and never comeback to my website, how am I unblock last item in database?

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no perfect way to handle this. You could use a timer to reserve the items only for a certain time, or just allow the second order to go through in the rare case where two users pay for the same item at the same exact time - just because an item is out of stock now doesn't mean it will be forever. Make sure that a user can cancel their order easily if needed. [Read more here](http://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/133925/best-practice-to-manage-concurrency-into-a-basket-in-a-e-commerce-website)

Comment: It is a good idea to reserve for a certain time. Some websites (railway) informs a user that his seat is hold just for 20mins to pay for it.

Comment: What happens if someone has a two web-crawlers (with faulty credit card information in both) looping through this process? Stock could read 0 for other users...